# Find most significant/informative review or create new review

Tags: nlp, nltk, text-analysis, semantic-analysis

Given a list of reviews (10000+), such as:

- has great pizzas, price is low and customer service is average
- Customer service was horrible, there was a long wait during lunch, food was ok
- has amazing pizzas and I highly recommend it, they also have deals/specials weekly. Very upscale, and the atmosphere is great

  etc.

The goal is to find the most significant reviews (around 20) out of all. The review should encapsulate as much information about the merchant as possible. (`Food satisfaction`, `Price`, `Wait Time`, etc)

I have been looking at some ways of doing this, chunking/collocation/idf but not sure if any of them are viable.

Comment: Can also create new reviews from given reviews, such as:
Pizza is good, Service is bad, price is average

Answer (score 0):

You can do a multi-label classification task for each review, then:

- You can retrieve the reviews with more tags (order by count(tags) desc)
- Give weight (positive or negative) to the labels and retrive the rewiews with max(sum(weight)) ORDER DESC

in both cases you can exclude labels or reviews with certain labels